How to Import python modules in Solana Playground?
I'm testing the Smart contract in seahorse and can't find the way to import python modules like time, random etc. Is there any way as I'm getting error of:
> Building...
Error: could not find import at /src + time.
7 | import time
    ^

Build error: Seahorse compile failed

I need to show the current time in read_hello and to use time in future contracts.
Code:
from seahorse.prelude import *
import time

# automatically when you build the project.
declare_id('HPUqbb9MaGxzvRsvuUP8nbHhYGpvkv1CpzcNPahrRmGK')

# Define the HelloWorld Account
class HelloWorld(Account):
    message: str


# Initialize the HelloWorld Account
@instruction
def init_hello(owner: Signer, hello_world: Empty[HelloWorld]):
    # Initialize the account with a payer and seeds
    hello_world.init(payer=owner, seeds=["hello_world", owner])



# Read the Message from HelloWorld Account
@instruction
def read_hello(hello_world: HelloWorld):
    print("Stored message:", hello_world.message)
  

# Write a new message to the HelloWorld Account
@instruction
def write_hello(hello_world: HelloWorld, new_message: str):
    hello_world.message = new_message 
 

